# Unable to run simulator for iPhone3GS from xcode3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, deployment, simulator

I'm unable to run simulator for testing iPhone3GS below version of 4.0. I have built my app with xcode4 and now, I want to test it how it works in iPhone3GS. I have read that I should install previous version of xcode, so I have installed xcode3. My IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is set to 3.1 in projects settings (xcode3). But still I can't see any iphone versions below 4.0 in simulator select list. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of, the latest version of Xcode 3 only comes with the iOS 4.* SDK so there is no iOS 3 simulator.

You will need to installe a version of Xcode 3 with iOS 3.* SDK to get the 3.* simulator, but you can only get them in de bundle version of Xcode.

What I do is test my apps on a device running iOS 3.1.2 with Xcode 4 and dropping support for iOS 3.* in new projects (94% of my user have switch to iOS 4).

Comment: What I want to do is to test for both retina (960x640) and iPhone3GS (480x320) resolution. I have iPhone4 but I haven't iPhone3.

Comment: The default simulator for iOS 4 is will display 480x320 but you can set it to retina `hardware -> device -> iphone(retina)`

Answer (score 0):

in this case you have to click the target section of the xcode and thre you have to chage the setting >build>latest ios.

Answer (score 0):

You can make and add hoc build and install it on an real device that run the desired os version.